# persistence.xml : hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have a problem with create-drop in my app.

In persistence.xml file I have line:

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop" value="create-drop"/>`

but every time when I restarting my app hibernate_sequence don't reset. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct naming is:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

The property name is `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` and not `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`

Comment: when I do this I get

`WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "drop table Indeks if exists" via JDBC Statement


org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table Indeks if exists" via JDBC Statement 

 at 

[...] 

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Nie można skasować "INDEKS" ponieważ zależy od "FKS9O4U4X1HIRR6HNWF5URMO7CW"

Cannot drop "INDEKS" because "FKS9O4U4X1HIRR6HNWF5URMO7CW" depends on it; SQL statement:

drop table Indeks if exists [90107-200]`

Comment: @Karol there is a table that depends on the it. Are you cascading the related entities ?

Comment: yes: in Index.java `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "indeks", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Student student;`

and in Student.java: `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Indeks indeks;`